# Batch file randomly creates undeletable twin of intended file

Tags: batch-file

I'm fumbling around in the dark a little, so please bear with me if I've missed something basic.

We needed to implement a new project management process in our department. So I created a batch file to ask for the name of a project, then copy a template file structure and rename various files within them to the name supplied, then open a word document. The initial catch was that this all had to be done on a network drive. Fairly straightforward stuff in theory, however for one of my colleagues it occasionally does something quite irritating. Instead of creating one copy of the file structure, it creates 2. This second one that it creates is unaccessible, and also undeletable. I can't replicate the error on my own laptop, and happens roughly 1 in 3 times. I can't work out why it would create this second file, or why on earth it would be unremovable once created. Can anyone shed any light?

Here's the code of the file I'm using:

```
@echo off
pushd $networkdrive\folder\Projects
SET initDir=$networkdrive\folder\Projects
SET newDir=
SET /p ver=<"$networkdrive\folder\projectnum.txt"

SET /P newDir=Please enter the title of the new project: %=%

IF DEFINED newDir (
    MD "$networkdrive\folder\Projects\%ver%. %newDir%\"
    SET initDir="%initDir%\%ver%. %newDir%\"
)

xcopy "$networkdrive\folder\Creative Briefing Template" %initDir% /s/e

ren %initDir%"1. Campaign Initiation"\"Campaign Initiation Document.docx" "%newDir% Initiation Document.docx"
ren %initDir%"2. Campaign Development"\"Project Finances.xlsx" "%newDir% Project Finances.xlsx"
ren %initDir%"2. Campaign Development"\"1. Briefing"\"Creative Briefing Document.docx" "%newDir% Creative Briefing Document.docx"
ren %initDir%"2. Campaign Development"\"1. Briefing"\"Integrated CRM brief.xlsx" "%newDir% CRM Brief.xlsx"
ren %initDIR%"3. Final Assets and Sign Off Document"\"Sign off sheet.docx" "%newDir% Sign off sheet.docx"

SET /a newVer=%ver%+1
echo %newVer% > "$networkdrive\folder\projectnum.txt"

%initDir%"1. Campaign Initiation"\"%newDir% Initiation Document.docx"

popd
cls
```

Comment: What is `$networkdrive`?

Comment: The file is hosted and runs on a network drive. I didn't want to give the full file name so I replaced it with $networkdrive/folder/

Comment: What do you mean by _"This second one that it creates is unaccessible, and also undeletable"_? What the folder and/or filenames that are unaccessible and undeletable?

Comment: When the bug occurs, in the root of the folder, there will be 2 identical copies of the file. One works as expected and contains everything in it. The other, when clicked, produces an error saying the following. "$folder refers to a location that is unavailable. It could be on a hard drive on this computer, or on a network. Check to make sure that the disk is properly inserted, or that you are connected to the Internet or your network, and then try again. If it still cannot be located, the information might have been moved to a different location." If I try to delete the file, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's not possible to reproduce your problem outside of your environment, I'd suggest a few changes:

Insert a `setlocal` command immediately after the `@echo on` line so that any variable changes within the routine are discarded when the routine ends.

Change your `set` syntax so that it follows the `set "var=value"` formula. This will mean that you don't have crazy amounts of `"` characters to balance - just one before `%var%` and one at the end of the required string. Personally, I'd also remove the `\\` as the last character of the directoryname and insert it as required when you use the variable.

When you set `ver` (a logical but inadvisable name since `ver` is an inbuilt command) you should *immediately* write the new version number out so that if the user is interrupted (phone call, coffee, being "managed") then there's the least possibility that the current number is acquired by another user (before it's updated by the current one). This would probably be best managed by

```
(for /f %%a in (%filename%) do set whatever=%%a&set /a newnum=%%a+1&call echo %%newnum%%>%filename%)
```

Finally, consider what will happen if `newdir` is empty or contains illegal/unexpected characters.